# canvas.toDataURL is returning black image while picking pic with cordovaImagepicker

Tags: html, image, cordova, canvas

I am using html canvas for resizing image.when i am loading image from project folder ,I am passing image path(img/tom.jpg)to canvas.draw method.After that i am getting base64url and then i am appending that url to the img src,That's working perfectly.But when i am picking image in cordova with cordovaImagepicker and then i am passing response url to canvas draw method ,i am getting base64 url but when i am appending that url to img src ,its coming totally black as square.Please help me ..

Here is my html(here in dummyImage {{this is image url that i picked up from device gallery}}):-

```
  <img id="sourceImage" src="" style="display:none;">
          <img id="dummyImage" width="150" height="150" src="{{image}}" alt="The Scream" style="display:none;">
          <canvas id="myCanvas" width="230" height="230"style="display:none;">
    <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img = document.getElementById("dummyImage");

        ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, 230, 230);

        $('#sourceImage').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg"));
        $.getScript('js/test.js');

    });
      </script>
```

Here is my console where in dummyImage(img tag id),i am getting picked image url and in sourceImage i am getting  canvas resized url and see i am getting black image...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your problem probably lies in using `src="file:///data/data/..."`. The source should be something like `/path/to/picture.jpg`.

The canvas itself is not a black square, that's just the image rendering of an empty/transparent canvas. To confirm this, just remove display:none from the canvas element.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u857pehs/1/

Comment: I don't want to display image there so that i have written display:none.Actually "file:///data/data/..."is the path which is coming when i am picking image from device gallery then i am just resizing image and passing to src...but here i am not dislaying image .I want to display it with jquery ...appened method....when i am passing local file path as u passed is working pefectly as i said..

Comment: I understand, but I think that using drawImage with an image loaded with the `file://` protocol might be an illegal canvas operation.